# Solid of revolution about arbitrary axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I'd like to rotate the region between y=cos(x) and y=x^2 - 0.25*pi^2 about the line x=pi. How to do this? So far I have only managed to rotate around the x-axis:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={60}{30}]
    \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,
      samples=20,
      color=red, opacity=0.15,
      domain=-0.5*pi:0.5*pi, y domain=0:2*pi,
      z buffer=sort]
     ({x * cos(deg(y))}, {x * sin(deg(y)) }, {cos(deg(x))});
   \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,
     samples=20,
     color=red, opacity=0.15,
     domain=-0.5*pi:0.5*pi, y domain=0:2*pi,
     z buffer=sort]
    ({x * cos(deg(y))}, {x * sin(deg(y)) }, {x*x - 0.25*pi^2});
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which produces: 
[image: solid of revolution]

However, the solid should be more of a donut shape.

Edit:
To clarify, I wish to produce a graphic of the solid that this rotation will generate:
[image: question]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Revolution about an arbitrary axis sounds more like you need to look up how a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rotation_matrix) looks like in 3D.

Comment: Also, how is `x=pi` a line? It's a plane, I'd say.

Comment: @Turion That rotation matrix stuff looks complicated. Even if I understood the mathematical basis behind it (which I probably could if I spent some time on it), I still wouldn't know how to implement it in tikz\LaTex. Also, from my problem set, "revolved around the line x = pi". The original question was not presented in an x,y,z coordinate system, I only introduced x,y,z in an attempt to plot the solid of revolution.

Comment: @thejmazz, ok, if you're not interested in rotations about arbitrary axes, we should be able to do it without. I still don't understand what is meant by "the line x = pi". To specify a line, you either need two constraints on coordinates (like `x=pi, y=0`) or a base vector and a direction vector.

Comment: @Turion What do you need to specify a line in the 2d x,y plane? Is x=pi not sufficient? The original question was to rotate a bounded region of some function f:X -> Y around an "offset" of the y-axis(x=0) - x=pi. I am not sure of the terminology of a "line" when rotating in 3d x,y,z. ...So does rotating around a line in 2d produce a rotation around a plane in 3d? I'll add a photo of the original question to the post.

Comment: Ah yes, in 2d you only need x = pi. So you embed 2d into 3d in the z=0 plane, so the axis of rotation is x=pi, z=0. I'll try to write an answer when I'm at the computer.

Comment: You might also check out [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net), which has better support for 3d than TikZ does. Surfaces of revolution are discussed in [my tutorial](http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf) in section 3.6 (currently page 61).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to find out how to describe the coordinates in term of your chosen coordinates. I choose `x` running between the values of the intersections of `y=cos(x)` and `y=x²-0.25π`, [which is roughly `-1.11` to `1.11`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-1%2F4pi%3Dcos%20x). The other coordinate (`y`) then is the angle of rotation. If you then express the three kartesian components in term of these variables, you get:

- `x' = (π-x)*cos(y)+π`
- `y' = cos(x)` or `y = x²-0.25π`
- `z' = (π-x)*sin(y)`

This you then can plot.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={60}{30}]
    \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,
      samples=20,
      color=red, opacity=0.15,
      domain=-1.11:1.11, y domain=0:2*pi,
      z buffer=sort
      ]
     ({(pi-x)*cos(deg(y))+pi}, {cos(deg(x))}, {(pi-x)*sin(deg(y))});
   \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,
     samples=20,
     color=blue, opacity=0.15,
     domain=-1.11:1.11, y domain=0:2*pi,
     z buffer=sort]
    ({(pi-x)*cos(deg(y))+pi}, {x*x-0.25*pi}, {(pi-x)*sin(deg(y))});
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** If you want to see the "donut" shape clearer, you can use make all axes scale the same, with the `unit vector ratio` option:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [   view={45}{20},
    unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
    xmin=-2, xmax=8,
    ymin=-3, ymax=2,
    zmin=-5, zmax=5,
    width=15cm,
    ]
    \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,
      samples=20,
      color=red, opacity=0.15,
      domain=-1.11:1.11, y domain=0:2*pi,
      z buffer=sort,
      ]
     ({(pi-x)*cos(deg(y))+pi}, {cos(deg(x))}, {(pi-x)*sin(deg(y))});
   \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,
     samples=20,
     color=red, opacity=0.15,
     domain=-1.11:1.11, y domain=0:2*pi,
     z buffer=sort]
    ({(pi-x)*cos(deg(y))+pi}, {x*x-0.25*pi}, {(pi-x)*sin(deg(y))});
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: That's awesome! This question was quite old (and I've long since handed in the assignment), but thanks for the answer! Definitely play around with this in the future :)

Comment: @thejmazz: I'm glad you like it. It was quite fun to solve this!